# PHP/MYSQL - Possible to use php variable inside of mysql field value?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am trying to get a variable to display, when used as part of a value inside of a mysql table.

To explain my problem, i am going to use a simple example
my script would contain something like this:

```
$variable = 'cool';
```

The value inside of the mysql field would be something like this:

```
This is '.$variable.' wow
```

When i echo this value, it displays as:

```
This is '.$variable.' wow
```

I want it to display as:

```
This is cool wow
```

Here are the two queries i am working with:

```
$linkQuery3 = 'SELECT model FROM models WHERE model_id = "'.$pageModel.'"
';
$sql15 = mysql_query($linkQuery3) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql15) == 0) {
die('No model results.');
} else {
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql15)) {
$model = ($row['model']);
}
}


$linkQuery2 = 'SELECT l.link , l.desc , l.domId , d.domain 
FROM links l 
INNER JOIN domains d 
ON d.domId = l.domId 
WHERE l.catId="'.$pageCat.'" && (l.modId="1" || l.modId="'.$pageModel.'")
ORDER BY domain
';
$sql3 = mysql_query($linkQuery2) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql3) == 0) {
die('No link results.');
} else {
$pageContent .= '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)) {
$linkAd = stripslashes($row['link']);
$linkDesc = ($row['desc']);
$linkDomain = ($row['domain']);
$pageContent .= '
    <li><a href="'.$linkAd.'" target="_tab">'.$linkDesc.' '.$linkDomain.'</a></li>
';
}
}
```

Basically, I want to use

```
$model
```

as part of the value inside of the desc field. When

```
$linkDesc
```

is echoed, this will be part of the outcome when

```
$pageContent
```

is echoed. It should display the text along with the value of

```
$model
```

, not just display

```
'.$model.'
```

As it currently does...

To view an example of this, you can check out http://www.free4blackberry.com/downloads/9800/apps.php it is one of my pages on my website, near the bottom of the page, you will see a list of links. The 7th one from the bottom links to en.softonic as

```
$linkDomain
```

If you read the text of the link you will clearly see my problem.

What am i missing here guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, try to do more simple, your question is too long.
But, based on what I understood I think that what you need is store a variable on database field like:

```
  "This is '" .$variable. "' wow"
```

If true, so when you will save the value you can serialize it before save on database and unserialize when rescue from database, like this:

```
  "INSERT INTO may_table (field) values (" . serialize("This is '$variable' wow") . ")";
  $model = unserialize($row['field']);
```

So when you rescue the value "$model" will return as a php variable.

Note: I put here just a example of how you could use the serialize/unserialize php functions and not the complete script.

I did a test and the works fine on this way:

```
  $c = serialize("This is '$variable' wow");
  $variable = "test";
  echo unserialize($c); //outputs This is 'teste' wow
```

Try again please.

Comment: I am sorry for the drawn out question, but that is why i provided a link to my site as a clear example. Your answer seems to be the solution to my problem, from how i take it. I will play around with this and see if i can get it to work, thanks!

Comment: No problem, let me know the result.

Comment: Hmm, data displayed from the value is displayed as pure text, therefore as in my original problem, it will not recognize the fact that the serialize function is being used, it merely outputs the string as is. I need a way to get it to recognise that I have used a php element within the string, so it looks like eval is my only real option. Although str_replace may work, im just not sure how as of yet.

Comment: I tried doing this `$linkDes = serialize($row['desc']);` `$linkDesc = unserialize($linkDes);` Unfortunately it does not seem to decode $linkDes as containing a php variable, again it only outputs whatever text is in the value.

Comment: can you put here the value assigned to $row['desc']?

Comment: A great collection of free software for your '.$model.', at

Comment: the value must be formatted on this way: "A great collection of free software for your '$model'", the secret is the quotes.

Comment: "A great collection of free software for your '.$model.'" en.softonic.com    -    That is what is displayed, gosh, so close :)

Comment: The solution to my problem came in the form of preg_replace()

Comment: Why store the variable when you can just store and retrieve the variable's value? I have no idea why you are trying to do this. It makes no sense to me. I also realize this post is a year old.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the eval function will work. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: I have tried eval, it chops my page to peices with errors. I believe it is suited more for use with javascript over php?

Comment: Okay scrach that, it may work in my case, the only problem is that the value of `$model` is drawn out of a value in a field on another mysql table. It is not a set string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, I don't recommend eval functions but they may help. you can replace the value with str_replace function though...

Comment: I don't think its possible either, its a pity because everytime I have a good idea it seems that technology is out to thwart my plan. *sigh* Can someone please provide with with an example of how i would use str_replace in my situation?